# Batch Program - Prime Number Checker

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm programming in batch using the fact that forall `n` between 1 and 100, `(2^n-2) mod n` is 0 if `n` is prime, and not 0 if otherwise. When I run the program, I get a "missing operator" error. What is the flaw in my code?

```
@echo off
color F0
title Prime Number Checker
echo --------------------------------------------------------
echo  Prime Number Checker v1.0
echo --------------------------------------------------------
echo.
set /p n=Enter a number between 1 and 100: 
set result=1
set i=1
:multiply
set /a result=result*2
set /a i=i+1
if %i% lss %n% goto multiply
set /a result = result - 2
set /a result = result % n
if %result% == 0 echo The number is prime.
if %result% NEQ 0 echo The number is not prime.
pause <nul
```

Comment: You need two % in a batch file for the modulus operator.

Comment: `set /a result = result % n` should be `set /a result = result %% n`

Comment: @LukeCollins, the modulus operator is the % symbol.

Comment: This is the way I would do it: `set /A "result=((1<<n)-2) %% n"`. Explanation: `1<<n` take the number 1 and shift it n bits to the left; the result is equivalent to `2^n`. See: `set /?` for further details.

Comment: @Aacini `set /A "((1<<n)-2) %% n"` results to `-2` for any `n>31` because numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision in `set /A` command. The OP should switch to another language or (better) to another algorithm or (the best) change both language and algorithm:)

Comment: @JosefZ: You are right! Which programming language do you suggest in order to perform the `((1<<n)-2) %% n` operation with n between 32 and 100?

Comment: @Aacini: please forgive my half-baked allusion to at least 128-bit _integral_ arithmetic (not found any implementation, sorry).